# Panel data ID and time level fixed effects with propensity score matching possible?

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, propensity-scores, effects

I have about 15000 observations on long term care centers per year, for a period of 10 years. My independent variable is binary and the outcome variable is continuous. I have performed ID and year level fixed effects in the past (by using i.year, fe). I was exploring the possibility of using a propensity score method along with ID and year level fixed effects to improve causal inference. Is that possible?  Which of the PS methods would be most appropriate?

Comment: I meant "propensity score methods" in my question. Matching is one of the options I was thinking about

Comment: There is not enough here to provide an answer. What is your treatment? Is it measured every period? What is your causal estimand? Is there confounding?

Comment: I would simply suggest IPTW using year and ID as additional modeling features.

Comment: @Noah yes, treatment is measured at every period. Once it changes from 0 to 1, it doesn't become 0 again. I am trying to measure the impact of adoption of a technology on a proportion of individuals receiving appropriate care. Yes there is confounding, but i have only some of those variables in my model

Comment: Take a look at this, we face the same problem but I just cannot understand this procedure...(http:// dx. doi. org/ 10. 1136/annrheumdis- 2018- 213731).